# Summits of Two Mountains subtended by an Angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$A$ and $B$ are summits of two mountains rise from a horizontal plain. $B$ is $1200\,\mathrm{m}$ above the plain. Find the height of point $A$. It is given that the angle of elevation as seen from a point $C$ on the plain (in the same vertical plane with $A$ and $B$) is $50^\circ$, while the angle of depression of $C$ viewed from $B$ is $25^\circ58'$ and the angle subtended at $B$ by $AC$ is $50^\circ$.

The Answer is $3002.33\,\mathrm{m}$

[image]

But I keep on getting $2421.51311\,\mathrm{m}$. Am I misinterpreting the word "subtended"? "The angle subtended at $B$ by $AC$ is $50^\circ$," so the angle must come from $B$ ...

Comment: What is the 28°58" figure that appears in several places on your diagram, where the textual description seems to have 25°28' ?

Comment: sorry. wrong notation. but it's still in arcminutes.

Comment: x @james: Even so, why are the _digits_ different?

Comment: Note also that $2508.437994$ is $1200$ divided by the sine of 28.58° rather than of 28°58'.

Comment: sorry its really 28°58' ! typo; changed it.

Comment: Now the text says 25°58' ...

Comment: Using your geometric drawing i get 1537,5 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both 2421 m and 3000 m sound wrong. Since the angle at B has about half below the horizontal and half above it, there's no way that A can be twice as high above the plain as C.

... except if C is actually on the plain *between* A and B, rather than on the far right as your sketch shows.

Additionally, your sketch shows a multiplication by $\tan 50^\circ$ to get the final height. That should be a multiplication by $\sin 50^\circ$. If your $x$ is the length of AC, the height of A must be *smaller* than $x$, not larger than it.